# SQL dividing 2 columns in multiple rows then adding it all up

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL db which has a bunch of columns in but the two which are important are the "power" and the "td" (time difference) columns.

I need to divide "power" by "td" in each row and add up all rows for a set time period.

I know the `WHERE year(time) = year(getdate()) AND month(time) = month(getdate()) AND day(time) = day(getdate()) ORDER BY (time) DESC` part to pick only the rows which are applicable for today.

How do I divide column "power" by column "td" for each row and then add all of these rows together in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
Select SUM(power/td) from sometable where time = GetDate() order by time DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(power/td)
from mytable
WHERE year(time) = year(getdate()) 
AND month(time) = month(getdate()) 
AND day(time) = day(getdate())
```

You don't need the `ORDER BY` as you are aggregating the rows.

Comment: Thanks. The ORDER BY was an afterthought which I was unsure of needing so thanks for that too.